# A Scala function that returns one of two types of Slick TableQuerys

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

Suppose I have the following trait.

```
trait ModelTrait{
  def id: Option[Long]
  def name: String
}
```

And that I have two tables. Their case classes and tableQuery fields are shown below.

```
val modelOneTable = TableQuery[ModelOnes]
val modelTwoTable = TableQuery[ModelTwos]

case class ModelOne(id: Option[Long], name: String) extends ModelTrait

case class ModelTwo(id: Option[Long], name: String) extends ModelTrait
```

I'd like to create a function that, depending on it's input, returns one of the tableQuery fields. Something like this:

```
def getTableQuery(which: String): TableQuery[Table[ModelTrait]] = {
which match {
   case "One" => modelOneTable
   case _ => modelTwoTable
}
```

Note that `modelOneTable` is `TableQuery[ModelOnes]`. The `ModelOnes` (with an s) class extend `Table[ModelOne]`. This is the same for `ModelTwo`. Hence why the function returns `TableQuery[Table[ModelTrait]]`.

```
class ModelOnes(tag: Tag) extends Table[ModelOne](tag, "modelOnes") {
  // ...
}

class ModelTwos(tag: Tag) extends Table[ModelTwo](tag, "modelTwos") {
  // ...
}
```

But I'm getting type mismatch errors in my case statements. Can anyone help?

Comment: Where is `TableQuery` defined?

Comment: @giorgio-b It's a Slick library class. You can add it as dependency in your `build.sbt` file `"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.2.3"`

Comment: I think it is impossible because of Table class is invariant `abstract class Table[T](_tableTag: Tag, ...`. It would be possible if it was covariant like `class Table[+T]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify case clause for other strings:

```
which match {
   case "One" => modelOneTable
   case "Two" => modelTwoTable
   case _ => ... // which TableQuery should be returned for other strings
}
```

Comment: Sorry, in my actual configuration, I do have it written like that but I still get the error. I will edit the question.